# Is there a way to change content offset via Core Animation on UIScrollView with reusing views?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, core-animation

EDIT: I got some progress, so I have simplified and narrowed the problem: [I have created new question, which is more clearer and more understandable I hope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209849/how-to-call-scrollviewdidscroll-the-same-way-uiscrollview-does-but-during-cust)

---

I have very large horizontally scrolling UIScrollView, which is reusing its subviews. When user scrolls left, the rightmost view is moved to the leftmost position and its content is updated. Similarly when user scrolls right, the leftmost view is moved to the rightmost position and its content is updated. Similarly like in UITableView. This works nicely using scrollviewDidScroll: delegate method.

Now I need to change offset programatically, but with custom animation behaviour (inertia and bounce back to the final position).

To prototype this, I use

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:contentOffsetCADuration 
                      delay:0 
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^{
                      [self setContentOffsetNoDelegateCalls:contentOffset animated:NO];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finish){
                      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                          [timer invalidate];
                      });
                 }];
```

where I animate content offset with disabled delegate callback, so that views are not messed during animation. But I need something to simultaneously reuse and reposition them.

My solution is to create timer and call `scrollViewDidScroll:` manually so that reusing works as usual, parallel to animation. But it simply does not work - nothing is reused and scrollview's content after animation is in the same state as before animation -> formerly visible pages are moved out of screen.

**So the question narrows down how to move subviews and update their content during animation?**

Or maybe there might be completely different way doing this ...

Comment: Not sure I understand - "so the views are not messed during animation", and then the question "how to move subviews ... during animation".  Why not call setContentOffset:animated: ?  Then scrollViewDidScroll gets called, and you reposition your subviews as always?

Comment: Yes, but I need custom animation. I have subclassed UIScrollView actually, and override setContentOffset:animated:. If animated is yes, I need to perform Core Animation custom animation. The problem is, that during this custom animation I am not able to reuse subviews.

Comment: When you perform setContentOffset:animated: within animation block, viewDidScroll is not called, instead some other delegate methods are called in the beginning and end of the animation, which I do not want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10209929/796103).

**Edit:** lol, just noticed it's the same author

Answer (score -1):

you may try to change scroll offset in a methode then you can call it from

```
    [self performSelector:<#(SEL)#> withObject:<#(id)#> afterDelay:<#(NSTimeInterval)#>];
```

then make it stop when it reaches a specific value